# PHPOffice/PHPExcel File cannot open file because the file format or file extension is not valid

Tags: php, excel, file, phpexcel

Just git cloned the latest branch to my MacBook Pro, not even the included Excel 2007 examples work. Upon running the 01simple-download-xlsx.php script I get the following error from Excel: **"File cannot open file because the file format or file extension is not valid"** However the 01simple-download-xls.php (Excel 2003) works 100%

I have tried the following answers from stackoveflow:

1. Edited the generated file with vim and found that it's empty with a 0 byte file size, although it does seem to have a blank line at the top.
2. Full error logging is on by default but no errors shown in aforementioned file.
3. Tried ob_start(), ob_clean() made no difference.
4. Set the header to encode the file as utf8 without BOM.
5. Ensured that the required PHP extensions are loaded on my system.

I'm sure the problem lies with my local setup but cant seem to find the problem. Running OS X El Capitan with XAMPP as my stack server. PHP version is 5.6.3.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Either the client side is flawed or the server side. But if the file is 0 bytes, then the problem appears to be at the serve side.

Try running it elsewhere, preferably on a Windows PC. I have used PHPExcel using XAMPP and all examples work out of the box.

Comment: This works on 2 other platforms, so the problem is with my setup.